# How to retrieve elements properties (project metadata)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

How can I get the urn

(The Base64 (URL safe) encoded)
For a project located in BIM 360 in order to retrieve all the elements properties (the metadata) using this api:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/

Answer (score 0):

There is another sample demos how to dump metadata of BIM360 file : https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360appstore-model.derivative-nodejs-xls.exporter.

While please note, if GET: Properties (no matter BIM360 file or generic OSS files)s, Forge service will not return the property if the volume > 20M unless you specify the query param **forgeceget = true** . this blog tells more:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forceget-options-get-properties

The sample above does not add **forgecget =true**. If you find it does not work with a specific big file, you may hit the limitation. you would need to add the param yourself if you want to program based on the sample.